# Solr 6 Facet range query over streaming API

Tags: solr, solrj, facet, solrcloud, solr6

While migrating from Solr legacy faceting to Solr streaming API, how to implement the below parameters:

```
&facet = true
&facet.range = {!key=age_ranges}age
&f.age.facet.range.start = 0
&f.age.facet.range.end = 100
&f.age.facet.range.gap = 10
&facet.range = {!key=price_ranges}price
&f.price.facet.range.start = 0
&f.price.facet.range.end = 1000
&f.price.facet.range.gap = 50
&facet.field = a_field
&facet.minCount = 1
```

How can I implement these parameters using the new facet streaming with parallel functions. I understand rollup() functionality has to be used.But the documentation is limited and I am not able to understand the underlying functionality. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that Streaming API will help you to migrate.

> Streaming Expressions provide a simple yet powerful stream processing
>   language for SolrCloud. They are a suite of functions that can be
>   combined to perform many different parallel computing tasks. These
>   functions are the basis for the Parallel SQL Interface.

What you really should use to get facets is new [JSON Facet API](http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/), some additional [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceted+Search) is available.